# Passing value from View to Controller on button click inside table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So my issue is: I need to pass the **product.id** to my controller with the delete button click

I know this is pretty simple but im struggling, im new to ASP.NET and dont know how to do it. And couldn't do with other answers I found online.

**VIEW**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Product</th>
      <th scope="col">Refresh</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (Product product in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">@product.Id</td>
            <td scope="row">@product.name</td>
            <td scope="row">
                <button class="btn btn-warning ml-auto">
                    <span class="icon text-white-50">
                        <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>Refresh</span>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td scope="row">
                <a class="btn btn-danger">
                    <span class="icon text-white-50">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now in my controller I have this code, the issue is that I can't find a way to receive the ID after the button click.

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{

    return View();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. Example in view:

```
<td scope="row">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteItem(@product.Id)">Delete</button>
</td>


function DeleteItem(objId)
{
     $.post("/ControllerName/DeleteItem/", { id: objId },
            function (data) {
                if (data.toString() != "") {
                     //your method to refresh table or remove row   
                }
      });
}
```

Method example in controller:

```
public JsonResult DeleteItem(int id)
{
   // your logic to delete item nad return result
}
```